# Integral involving a Meijer-G function

Tags: integration, special-functions

I am having trouble with calculating the following integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln{(1 + \alpha x)\, G^{k,0}_{k,k}\left[e^{-x}\left|^{(a_k)}_{(b_k)} \right.   \right]} \, dx, 
$$
where $\alpha > 0$ and $G^{m,n}_{p,q}[\cdot | \cdot]$ is the Meijer-G function. Any ideas or references would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Have you asked Mathematica or Maple?

Comment: Maple does not even do the $G^{1,0}_{1,1}$ case, where the G can be evaluated in closed form first.